# How to copy a folder with subfoolder from server1 to server2 using jenkins SCP plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, scp

I want to copy a folder with its subfolder from server1 to server2. That works only  for artifacts. But now i want to copy an entire folder with its subfolders o that the structure of the directory maintains.

I'm using `publich artifacts to SCP repository` with `source: OutputManagement/**/*` and `Destination: OutputManagement/`. But i get all files without the corresponding folders.

For example:

```
  mainfolder:
      subfolder1:
           file1
           file2
      subfolder2:
           file3
           file4
```

So i get only mainfolder with file1-4 inside.

How can i do it to maintain the structure of my directory like above?!

Answer (score 0):

I overlooked there is a checkbox `Keep Hierarchy` checking that you will keep the structure of the directory.